# How to change text content in DIV (with DOM) to add SPANs elements instead?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm confused on how to change text content of div with the DOM. When event is triggered, I see that the new text replace the old but it is in a new div. I want to keep it in "transcriptText" to keep all attributes.`How can I do that?

This is my old div with text inside:

```
var transcriptText = document.getElementById("transcriptText");
```

these are my new text `SPAN` elements

```
var newTranscript = document.createElement("div");
```

This is how I handle the event

```
function EventHandler() {
    transcriptText.parentNode.replaceChild(newTranscript, transcriptText);
    }
```

Here is the JSFiddle on how it currently works:
http://jsfiddle.net/b94DG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing now is creating a new `div`, `newTranscript`, which you create by appending a bunch of spans based on the old text.  Then in your event handler you replace the old one with the new one.  Instead of that, you could still copy the text from the old one, but then clear it and append the children on the old `div`, replacing line 36 with:

```
transcriptText.appendChild(newSpan);
```

To clear the old element, it might work to just set `innerHTML` to `""`, or if necessary you could remove all the children with `removeChild` as described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild

EDIT:

I modified your fiddle to reflect this:

http://jsfiddle.net/b94DG/1/

Comment: Wow, thanks very much for the tip. I didn't realise that I wasn't clearing the old div and append the children. So much to learn....

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `innerHTML` of `transcriptText` instead of creating a new `div`.

```
var transcriptText = document.getElementById("transcriptText");
var divideTranscript = document.getElementById("divideTranscript");
divideTranscript.onclick = function() {
    var sArr = transcriptText.innerHTML.split(" ");
    var newInnerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++) {
        var item = sArr[i];
        var newText = "<span class='highlight' id='word" + i + "'>" + item + " </span>";
        newInnerHTML += newText;
    }
    transcriptText.innerHTML = newInnerHTML;

    var mouseOverFunction = function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    };
    var mouseOutFunction = function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = '';
    };

    var highlight = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight");
    for (i = 0; i < highlight.length; i++) {
        highlight[i].onmouseover = mouseOverFunction;
        highlight[i].onmouseout = mouseOutFunction;
    }
};
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khnGN/